# There's something missing in my pdo but I don't know what (php)

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to connect to my database with PDO but it doesn't work...

this is my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=Localhost;dbname=fisherman;charset=utf8;' , 'fisherman' , '********');
```

and this is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>
> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in
> /users/fisherman/www/MysticSouls_Website/config/config.php:8 Stack
> trace: #0
>
> /users/fisherman/www/MysticSouls_Website/config/config.php(8):
>
> PDO->__construct('mysql:host=Loca...', 'fisherman', '*******') #1
>
> /users/fisherman/www/MysticSouls_Website/Index.php(2):
>
> require_once('/users/fisherma...') #2 {main} thrown in
>
> /users/fisherman/www/MysticSouls_Website/config/config.php on line 8

I really can't find the problem..

Thank's for your help!

Comment: show onfig.php code

Comment: the code there and of course <?php  ?> is the config-code there isn't more

Comment: what does the "require_once..." mean?

Comment: reuqire once means when you need to include php file to the that file then it will be used

Comment: try to remove `;charset=utf8;`. Yo can set charset with `$pdo->prepare("SET NAMES utf8")->execute();`

Comment: when I remove charset, nothing happens.

Comment: try to use `127.0.0.1` as hostname

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn